# Inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices

If A and B are any matrices of order 2x1, how can we show that the product AB^t has no inverse?

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: It is easy to show that the columns of $AB^T$ are linearly dependent since both consist of scaled copies of $A$. In other words $AB^T= [b_1 A, b_2 A]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  a \\
  b\\
  \end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}
  c \\
  d\\
  \end{pmatrix}$$ then $$AB^t=\begin{pmatrix}
  ac & ad\\
  bc & bd\\
  \end{pmatrix}$$ Since $|AB^t|=0$ so it has no inverse.

Comment: Nice solution + 1

Comment: @Amzoti: Regards my friend. :)

Answer (score 4):

The rank of $A$ and the rank of $B$ are both equal to 1. since $AB^{T}$ is a 2x2 matrix its rank must be 2 for it to be invertible. but $rank(AB)\leq min(rank(A),rank(B))$ see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra) . Thus $AB^{T}$ cannot have an inverse